# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present .when using [HttpPost]

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

In my Controller:

When I use without [HttpPost] then it works.But when i use [HttpPost] before method it shows the following message:

Blockquote

'http://localhost:59446/Registration/RegistrationSave' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been 
 blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access- 
 Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How can I overcome this situation?

In my Controller:

```
    [AllowCrossSite]
    [HttpPost]     
    public JsonResult RegistrationSave(RegistrationInfo registration)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.RegistrationInfo.Add(registration);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        ProfileInfo info = new ProfileInfo();
        var registrationId = db.RegistrationInfo.Max(s => s.Id);
        info.RegistrationId = registrationId;
        info.Email = registration.Email;
        info.UserName = registration.Name;
        db.ProfileInfo.Add(info);
        return Json(new { status = "Successfully Registered" });
    }
```

AllowCrossSiteAttribute.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RegistrationApp.Models
 {

   public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
  {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {

        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
  "*");
       // filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow- 
        Credentials", "true");
        string rqstMethod = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"];
        if (rqstMethod == "OPTIONS" || rqstMethod == "POST")
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow- 
            Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow- 
           Headers", "X-Requested-With, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type");
        }

        //if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        //{
        //    //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        //    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        //}
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

  }
}
```

My Angular 9 Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({

providedIn: 'root'

})

export class LoginService {

 url="http://localhost:59446/Registration/RegistrationSave";

 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

_headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({

'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 

});

submitRegistrationInfo(data):Observable<any>{

 console.log(data);
 return this.http.post<any>(this.url,data,{headers:this._headers} );

 }
}
```

Comment: As the message indicates, it fails on the preflight which is an OPIONS request. So also allow OPTIONS and respond with the correct CORS headers.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add options request and can you give me an instance of correct CORS headers?

Comment: I’m not too familiar with asp.net mvc.. so I’m not sure how to accomplish that. The goal is to have your backend respond correctly on an OPTIONS request. There are plenty of CORS headers examples available, also on SO..

Comment: Ok..I have solved it by using webapi.config.cs and then configured cors policy

Comment: Ah cool man. Good luck!